# React: programmatically focus library components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a third-party radio button that loses tab focus when we interact with it via the keyboard; i.e. tabbing to it and then pressing enter causes the focus to move on to another element, when I want the focus to stay on the radio button. Is there a way to programmatically focus the radio button from inside its onChange handler? My code looks something like this, which doesn't work:

```
const Component = (event) =>{
   const handleChange = ()=>{
      //business logic
      event.target.focus()
   }
   return(<RadioBtn onChange={handleChange}/>)
}
```

I also tried using a ref but that didn't work either, did I do something wrong?

```
const Component = (event) =>{
   const rdbRef = useRef();

   const handleChange = ()=>{
      //business logic
      rdbRef.current.focus();
   }
   return(<RadioBtn 
           onChange={handleChange}
           ref={rdbRef}/>)
}
```

Comment: Well it depends on what the third party component renders/requires..... For example it probably renders a checkbox with a wrapper around it. It probably also overrides the onChange method... Also you might have to stop propagation of the event enter key... For example event.stopPropagation(); event.target.focus();

Comment: It looks like you have the "event" property as a parameter of the Component but not of the `handleChange` function. Is that a copying error?